# Incompatibility of scrbook and fontspec in TeX-Live 2013

Tags: xetex, texlive, fontspec, scrbook

Since updating to TeX-Live 2013 I am facing the following error:

Compiling the following file by XeLaTeX ...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
 bla
\end{document}
```

... ends up with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \str_if_eq_x_p:nn 

l.5 \end{document}
```

Replacing scrbook by scrartcl or scrreprt works smoothly. Also in my old TeX-Live 2012 installation the problem does not occur.

Comment: You have mismatched versions of `fontspec` and `l3kernel` (`expl3`): nothing to do with KOMA _per se_ (probably showing up as a different path is taken in the code). Can you post your log file as an edit?

Comment: Oh my goodness.

I happened to have all the l3-packages in my $(HOME)/texmf file.

Therefore the version mismatch occured.

I could have figured this out myself by checking the logfiles more carefully.

Thanks so much, problem solved.

Comment: I suspected something like that: this is quite a common one :-)